# onTouch() not called for parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, motionevent, android-touch-event, view-hierarchy

I have a layout like this:

```
LinearLayout
    RelativeLayout(id = test)
        FrameLayout (From a LIB. id = lib)
```

I tried to add `onTouchListener()` to `test` but it doesn't work.

I tried:

```
@OnTouch(R.id.test)
public boolean test(View v,MotionEvent e) { NOT WORK }
```

And i tried a simple listener:

```
    test.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
NOT WORK
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I tried to add listeners to `FrameLayout` but doesn't work too.

I don't want to modify library. 
Anyone have idea to use `OnTouch` event?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.flurgle.camerakit.CameraView
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:ckCropOutput="false"
            app:ckFacing="back"
            app:ckFlash="off"
            app:ckFocus="continuous"
            app:ckJpegQuality="100"
            app:ckMethod="standard"/>

    <TextView
```

In CameraView:

```
focusMarkerLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            int action = motionEvent.getAction();
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && mFocus == CameraKit.Constants.FOCUS_TAP_WITH_MARKER) {
                focusMarkerLayout.focus(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
            }

            mPreviewImpl.getView().dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

---

**Solution:**

---

```
LinearLayout
    RelativeLayout(id = test)
        CustomRelativeLayout()
            FrameLayout (From a LIB. id = lib)
```

Create CustomRelativeLayout

```
public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout{
    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Problem:

```
Touch 
-> Activity:dispatchTouchEvent 
-> LinearLayout:dispatchTouchEvent 
-> CustomRelativeLayout:dispatchTouchEvent 
-> CameraView:dispatchTouchEvent (return true) STOPPED everything
```

Solution:

```
Touch 
-> Activity:dispatchTouchEvent 
-> LinearLayout:dispatchTouchEvent 
-> CustomRelativeLayout:dispatchTouchEvent 
-> CustomRelativeLayout:onTouch
-> LinearLayout:onTouch
-> Activity:onTouch (IT WORK :))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most possibly `FrameLayout` consumes the touch event. Once the touch event is consumed by any view, that event won't be dispatched to the parent. If the `FrameLayout` has a click listener attached to it, then the `MotionEvent` won't reach `RelativeLayout`.

You can subclass `RelativeLayout`, override [`ViewGroup#dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) and track the `MotionEvent` that will be dispatched to children of that layout (in your case the `FrameLayout`).

In that case your view hierarchy would be this one:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <com.example.CustomRelativeLayout>
        <FrameLayout>
    </com.example.CustomRelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I Did my Custom layout with     @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
but its not work

Comment: That will only help you to debug `MotionEvent`s and see what's happening, it wasn't supposed to help you in any ways. Also, returning `false` won't allow to dispatch that `MotionEvent` to children, instead return `true` in order to let the `FrameLayout` handle the click.

Comment: The CustomLayouts dispatch is run when i touch the screen.

Comment: Custom layout solution works but if `dispatchTouchEvent` returns false, `FragmeLayout` can not take touch event. In my scenario `FragmeLayout` contains fragment so I slide the view which over the `FrameLayout`, the fragment can not handle touch events.

Answer (score 0):

I think your RelativeLayout is overridden by FrameLyout that's why touch is not working.
Post your layout xml code